# Need some advice about CoreText and sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-text

I'm creating a Bible App.
The Bible data was made by sqlite. 
I want my Bible App to look like Real Book.
So, I intend using CoreText instead of UIWebView.

I have some questions.

1) Is my way(using CoreText) the best way to look like Real? How about your thought?

2)  How make data for using CoreText from sqlite? What format? xml file?? 
    Bible DB file size isn't small.
    I have no idea. ......

3) Bible App should have [Search feature] and [Book mark feature].
   Can these feature be realized from CoreText?

I can't find sample codes and articles about this issue(-How to use CoreText using sqlite).

I need your advice. Please add your comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a few misconceptions here.

First, CoreText. It is a [set of C functions for rendering text](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html). It does not aid you in searching or bookmarking.

Also, your SQLite DB already has its own "format". You would query strings from your SQLite DB and then render it to a view, maybe with CoreText.

So SQLite is a tool to store and query information. CoreText is a tool to display strings. You will not find a tutorial or anything covering both at once as they are about totally distinct problems.

You need to learn about the basics first. So I suggest you do these things:

- First search tutorials about using SQLite (there are a lot of them) to get an idea about what it is and how you use it. Work through one or two of them to gain an understanding on how SQLite works, how you get data out of it.
- Then you can start planing a design on how to get the data out of your SQLite DB and process it in a way that is useful for your app.
- The next step is to render the text using normal UI elements, e.g. multiline `UILabel`.
- Once you have reached that stage you can think about making it beautiful and read about CoreText and how to use it. CoreText isn't easy to use as typography isn't easy. You will need to learn typographic basics to really get the most out of CoreText.